# Random sample from specific rows and columns of a 2d numpy array (essentially sampling by ignoring edge effects)

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a 2d numpy array size 100 x 100.
I want to randomly sample values from the "inside" 80 x 80 values so that I can exclude values which are influenced by edge effects. I want to sample from row 10 to row 90 and within that from column 10 to column 90.

However, importantly, I need to retain the *original* index values from the 100 x 100 grid, so I can't just trim the dataset and move on. If I do that, I am not really solving the edge effect problem because this is occurring within a loop with multiple iterations.

```
gridsize = 100
new_abundances = np.zeros([100,100],dtype=np.uint8)
min_select = int(np.around(gridsize * 0.10))
max_select = int(gridsize - (np.around(gridsize * 0.10)))
row_idx =np.arange(min_select,max_select)
col_idx = np.arange(min_select,max_select)
```

`indices_random = ?????` Somehow randomly sample from new_abundances only within the rows and columns of row_idx and col_idx set.

What I ultimately need is a list of 250 random indices selected from within the flattened new_abundances array. I need to keep the new_abundances array as 2d to identify the "edges" but once that is done, I need to flatten it to get the indices which are randomly selected.

Desired output:

An 1d list of indices from a flattened new_abundances array.

Comment: Please include you desired output. At the moment it is not clear which format you expect as a result.

Comment: Your description is still contradicting and unclear. Your question cannot be answered in its current form, so I voted to close it. If you want to improve your question you can take the [tour] or read more about [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woudl something like solve your problem?

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
mat = np.random.random(size=(100,100))

x_indices = np.random.randint(low=10, high=90, size=250)
y_indices = np.random.randint(low=10, high=90, size=250)

coordinates = list(zip(x_indices,y_indices))

flat_mat = mat.flatten()
flat_index = x_indices * 100 + y_indices
```

Then you can access elements using any value from the `coordinates` list, e.g. `mat[coordinates[0]]` returns the the matrix value at `coordinates[0]`. Value of `coordinates[0]` is `(38, 45)` in my case. If the matrix is [flattened](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.flatten.html?highlight=flatten), you can calculate the 1D index of the corresponding element. In this case, `mat[coordinates[0]] == flat_mat[flat_index[0]]` holds, where `flat_index[0]==3845=100*38+45`

Please also note that multiple sampling of the original data is possible this way.

Using your notation:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
gridsize = 100
new_abundances = np.zeros([100,100],dtype=np.uint8)
min_select = int(np.around(gridsize * 0.10))
max_select = int(gridsize - (np.around(gridsize * 0.10)))

x_indices = np.random.randint(low=min_select, high=max_select, size=250)
y_indices = np.random.randint(low=min_select, high=max_select, size=250)
coords = list(zip(x_indices,y_indices))

flat_new_abundances = new_abundances.flatten()
flat_index = x_indices * gridsize  + y_indices
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well, but with that solution I need to go from the list of 2d coordinates to a list of 1d indices. Instead of the matrix value at coordinates[0] I need the index value of the flattened array new_abundances.

Comment: Perhaps you could call `np.vstack((x_indices, y_indices))` instead of `list + zip`?

Comment: @ECM from a 2D index, such as `coordinates[0]`, you can make a 1D index easily, if that's what you need. Instead `(38, 45)`, you access `38*gridsize + 45` on a flat matrix. `coordinates[0][0] * gridsize + coordinates[0][1]`

Comment: Thank you to both @hilberts_drinking_problem and DanielTuzes, this is exactly what I needed. Problem solved, thanks!